# Javascript automatically parsing nested object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, object

This is more a question of procedure than anything else. I'm curious why this happens and I can't seem to find any documentation on this "feature" within the ECMA script documentation.

When I make an AJAX call within jQuery to my server, it returns the following JSON response to the page:

```
{"version":"v1","status":"OK","timestamp":"2013-02-14 10:32:45","data":"true","error":""}
```

With this string I have to call jQuery.parseJSON(string); to get it as an object, and the be able to reference it as an object.

However, when my server returns something like this:

```
{"version":"v1","status":"OK","timestamp":"2013-02-14 10:12:19","data":{"a":"asgsadfga","b":false,"c":[]},"error":""}
```

Javascript automatically loads this an an object without the need to parse. It would seem that because this example returns a nested object, despite the fact it was returned from the server as a string, Javascript will immediately recognize that, and parse the string for me.

Is this expected functionality, and if so, can anyone point me to the documentation of this?

EDITED:

Here is the offending AJAX call:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result)
        }
```

Comment: Show your code that is making the AJAX call, you're saying that something is happening but is not showing what code is causing it

Comment: The question I was asking was not related to my code, but more why the first string was only interpreted as a string by jQuery, but the second one was interpreted as an object. Various answers were give as to how I could fix this on both the front-end and the back-end. But what I really wanted to know was if there was any intelligent guessing as to what the contentType of the data was.

Comment: You were calling it differently in both contexts, weren't you? Don't hide your code, don't assume you know what's going on!

Comment: I've attached the AJAX call, as you can see I was passing no dataType or contentType, what I was looking for was the documentation on how and why jQuery was parsing one object but not another without any intervention by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ajax() in jQuery API Documentation under **dataType**:

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or
>   html))Type: String The type of data that you're expecting back from
>   the server. **If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based
>   on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in
>   1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object**, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was confused that without sending anything as a dataType to the server why some calls returned as an object, while other returned as a string. By default my server returns everything as a string. I was more wondering why some objects would be interpreted as strings and others as objects. This was the question I was asking, and this was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your server sets the proper Content-Type response HTTP header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

So that jQuery will automatically parse the JSON string returned by your server to a javascript object which will be passed as argument to your success callback.

Or if for some reason you've got some broken server side script which you have no control over you could set the `dataType` parameter to force jQuery to parse the result as JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/script.cgi',
    type: 'POST'
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        // result will be a javascript object 
    }
});
```

But obviously the proper thing to do is to fix your server side script to return the proper Content-Type response header.

Comment: Isn't the OP wondering why it's already parsed without calling `jQuery.parseJSON(string)` ?

Comment: No, it the first case he is saying that he needs to explicitly parse the object. But as I explained in my answer this has nothing to do with the JSON string returned by the server (assuming of course it is a valid JSON string) but with the `Content-Type` response HTTP header that the server sends. Also as I have explained in my answer if the server doesn't set this header properly (which is what I assume is happening in the first case) there's a possibility to force it on the client using the `dataType` parameter when making the AJAX call.

Comment: Actually I was asking why the first sting was not parsed while the second one was. The AJAX call was the same in both instances, the issue was that jQuery was able to determine that one was an object, but not the other. I wanted to know why and how this was happening.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify `dataType` to be `json` in your `$.ajax` call. dataType is the MIME you are expecting to receive from the server. contentType is what the server is expecting from you.

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to specify this if you have a properly written server side script which is correctly setting the `Content-Type` response HTTP header.

Comment: having read the specs again, you are right. IF the server specifies the Content-Type, then jQuery will infer the correct dataType. However given the fact that the OP sometimes gets json object, sometimes not, I guess his server is not specifying content type. So dataType in ajax should help.